# PHP not parsing variable within double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I have the following query:

```
var_dump($id); // string '51' (length=2)


$sql    = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

var_dump($myrow) // null (NOT OK)
```

When I change the $id for a hard-coded value(51) it works:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=51";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

var_dump($myrow); // array 0 => string '51' (length=2) (OK)
```

It's as if the $sql is not getting parsed correctly. It is a very old site, could it be something to do with the PHP version the site was originally created for?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=".$id; 
// ALSO WORKS. But I am not really looking forward to doing a FIND & REPLACE
```

**EDIT:**

The site has hundreds of these types of queries. It is an old site that was developed my somebody else. I was wondering if there was an INI setting or something that has been switched between PHP versions that I can switch back.

Thanks

PHP Version: PHP5.2

The site was build for version 4.something.

Comment: did you try some error handling? using the mysql_error function would be one option..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors returned.

Comment: PHP Version: PHP5.2

The site was build for version 4.something.

Comment: How are you checking whether errors are being returned? Also, how are you obtaining that `$id` in the first place? User input and then you clean the variable or?

Comment: Where does `$id` come from? Are you sure it contains ASCII 53/49? Try casting it to an int before you use it in the query - firstly, see what `var_dump((int) $id);` gives you, and then try changing the query string to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".((int) $id);`

Comment: How about doing a `var_dump` of `$sql`?

Comment: Thank, N.B. You made me check. $id was coming from $_REQUEST['id']. Which was nothing. :)

Comment: This should absolutely work. The problem is somewhere else

Comment: Perhaps it is an SQL error. I don't know if trying to perform a query like that would work without surrounding the $id in single quotes, because it's a string. Try `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";`

Answer (score 0):

rather than writing query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";
```

you can use this alternative also..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this please :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = $id
```

> insert ` in both side of id

Answer (score 0):

register_globals was turned off. I know the security implications but I have it on its own virtual server and haven't got time right now to fix it.

In htaccess:

```
php_flag register_globals on
```

Comment: You question was misleading if this was really the issue. Had you really validated that the variable contained 51 or you just made it up as you wrote the query?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact, that queries should be escaped (in this case casting to integer will suffice) or preferably created through prepared statements, my guess would be that it is the query that fails.

PHP have parsed double quoted strings since the beginning, so try outputting the value of `$sql` to see what gets sent to MySQL.